# Sacar un valor de la consulta Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

No he podido utilizar el resultado arrojado por una **consulta** de un **modelo** en **Codeigniter** como parametro para poder ejecutar otra **consulta** que requiere de la información anterior.

Código del **modelo**:

```
public function datosuser($codigo){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('codigo',$codigo);
    $resultado= $this->db->get('usuarios');
    return $resultado->result();
}

public function segundoautor($codigo2){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('codigo',$codigo2);
    $resss= $this->db->get('usuarios');
    return $resss->result();
}
```

y este es el **controlador**:

```
$sesion = $this->session->userdata('codigo');        
    if($sesion){  
        //cargando datos
        $datosu['usuarios'] = $this->principal_model->datosuser($sesion);
        $datosu['documentos'] = $this->principal_model->consultandodocumentos($sesion);

        foreach ($documentos as $documents){                 
            $datosu['datosa2'] = $this->principal_model->segundoautor($documents->codigouser2;)
        }

        $datosu['integrantes'] = $this->principal_model->usuarios(); 
        //views
        $this->load->view('paginaprincipal', $datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor1',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor2',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor3',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor4',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor5',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor6',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor7',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor8',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor9',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor10',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor11',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor12',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor13',$datosu);
        $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor14',$datosu);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es tu variable `$documentos`?

Comment: Honestamente puedes ejecutar consultas dentro de la vista, no es necesario que las envies por el controlador

Comment: @WillianRivera Es una muy mala práctica ejecutar consultas dentro de la vista ya que no estaría implementando MVC y entonces no tendría sentido el utilizar Codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es esta línea de código, que tienes el **";"** en donde no va:

```
foreach ($documentos as $documents){                 
            $datosu['datosa2'] = $this->principal_model->segundoautor($documents->codigouser2;) // el ; está mal ubicado
        }
```

Reemplaza por el siguiente código:

```
foreach ($documentos as $documents){                 
                $datosu['datosa2'] = $this->principal_model->segundoautor($documents->codigouser2); // el ; está mal ubicado
            }
```

**Actualización:** En base a tu comentario en mi respuesta podrías intentar lo siguiente:

Utiliza en tu **modelo** el siguiente código:

```
public function datosuser($codigo){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('codigo',$codigo);
    $resultado= $this->db->get('usuarios');
    return $resultado->result_array(); /* Para obtener un arreglo en vez de un objeto */
}

public function segundoautor($codigo2){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('codigo',$codigo2);
    $resss= $this->db->get('usuarios');
    return $resss->result_array(); /* Para obtener un arreglo en vez de un objeto */
}
```

y en tu **controlador** el siguiente código:

```
$sesion = $this->session->userdata('codigo');        
    if($sesion){  
        //cargando datos
        $datosu['usuarios'] = $this->principal_model->datosuser($sesion);
        $datosu['documentos'] = $this->principal_model->consultandodocumentos($sesion);

    foreach ($documentos as $row =>$documents){ /* Así se tiene cada valor de un arreglo sencillo */  
        $codigouser2=$documents['codigouser2']; /* Obtenemos lo que se va a pasar como parametro al segundo foreach */              
        $datosu['datosa2'] = $this->principal_model->segundoautor($codigouser2); /* Aplicamos el foreach con el parametro simple */
    }

    $datosu['integrantes'] = $this->principal_model->usuarios(); 
    //views
    $this->load->view('paginaprincipal', $datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor1',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor2',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor3',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor4',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor5',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor6',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor7',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor8',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor9',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor10',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor11',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor12',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor13',$datosu);
    $this->load->view('contenido/contenedor14',$datosu);
}
```

**Observación:** Las lineas a las que hice cambio las comente a un lado con la explicación para que sepas que hice.

Eso es todo, espero te sea útil. Un Saludo.

Comment: no me sirvio me salio un error en el navegador que dice : Content Encoding Error

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this pro gracias

Comment: @MateoNieto tu habilitaste gzip? para que lo utilizas? porque si no es necesario puedes deshabilitarlo en los archivos de configuración de codeigniter. Colocas compress_output en false así: `$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;`

Comment: @MateoNieto Revisa por favor mi respuesta la he actualizado

Comment: el problema estaba en el $config['compress_output']  lo tenia en true apenas lo cambie m sirvio MUCHAS GRACIAS!!

Comment: @MateoNieto De nada bro. Me alegra mucho que te fue de utilidad. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

si necesitas sacar un único valor, debes modificar el modelo para que sólo te arroje el valor deseado, ejemplo:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->where('campo','valor');
$query1 = $this->db->get();
$row_query1 = $query1->row_array();  //Aquí tomamos todo el registro de la consulta

//Lo usas en otra consulta
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table2');
$this->db->where('campo2',$row_query1['ID']);
.
.
.
//O tambien retornas directo
return $row_query1['ID'];
```

Dónde el índice "ID" le debes colocar el nombre del campo de la base de datos, o en vez de realizar un "select *", realizas un "select ID"